# Show that $\tau _f$ \ $\tau_{st}$ is uncountable.

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb R $ with the standard topology $\tau _{st}$. Suppose $\tau _ f$ is a topology on $\mathbb R $ such that $\tau _{st} \subset \tau_f$ (and not equal). Show that $\tau _f$ \ $\tau_{st}$ is uncountable.

Approach: Take $V \in \tau_f$ \ $\tau_{st}$. Then $V$ cannot be written as the union of open intervals $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R $. What's the next step?? Can someone give me a hint? I have to make uncountable new open sets with the intervals $(a,b)$ and V, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $V \in \tau_f \setminus \tau_{st}$. Then, note that there must be some interval $I = (a, a+1)$, where $a \in \mathbb R$, such that $V \cap I \notin \tau_{st}$, because you can check whether $V$ is an open set "locally". Yet, $V \cap I \in \tau_f$, because $I \in \tau_f$.

Then, for each $b > a + 1$, the set
$$
(V \cap I) \cup (b,\infty) \in \tau_f
$$
and this set does not lie in $\tau_{st}$. This gives $\mathbb R$-many elements in $\tau_f \setminus \tau_{st}$.

Comment: Great! Thanks!!